# What is the analytic continuation of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Take a smooth and somehow well-behaved function $n(x) $ defined on the interval $[a, b] \in \mathbb{R}$, say,

$$n(x ) = 1/((x-a)^2+ (x-b)^4  ) .$$

Now define a function on the complex plane

$$ G(z) =  \int_a^b \frac{n(x)d x}{z - x} . $$

The integral is well defined for arbitrary $z $ not on the interval $[a, b]$. The problem is that, $G(z)$ is not continuous across the cut $[a, b]$.

The question is then, how is the continuation of this function? For what kind of function $n(x)$, can we end up with a function defined on a finite-leaf Riemann surface?

Answer (score 0):

Let $c \in (a, b)$. We examine the jump size when we cross the branch cut $[a, b]$ downward along vertical line $\Re(z) = c$. That is, we consider the limit

$$ \Delta(c) := \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} [ G(c-i\epsilon) - G(c+i\epsilon) ]. $$

Using the substitution $y = (x - c)/\epsilon$, it follows that

\begin{align*}
G(c-i\epsilon) - G(c+i\epsilon)
&= \int_{a}^{b} \frac{2i\epsilon n(x)}{(x - c)^2 + \epsilon^2} \, dx \\
&= \int_{(a-c)/\epsilon}^{(b-c)/\epsilon} \frac{2i n(c + \epsilon y)}{y^2 + 1} \, dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2i n(c + \epsilon y)}{y^2 + 1} \mathbf{1}_{[(a-c)/\epsilon, (b-c)/\epsilon]}(y) \, dy.
\end{align*}

Since $n(x)$ is bounded on $[a, b]$, the integrand of the last integral is dominated by the integrable function $C/(y^2+1)$ for some constant $C > 0$. Thus by the dominated convergence theorem, as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, we have

$$ \Delta(c) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2i n(c)}{y^2 + 1} \, dy = 2\pi i n(c). $$

---

If $G$ can be continuated across $(a, b)$, then $\Delta = 2\pi i n$ is a difference between two analytic function. To be precise, let $G_{+}$ (resp. $G_{-}$) be an analytic continuation of $G$ which extends $G$ restricted on the upper half plane $\Bbb{H}_+$ (resp. the lower half plane $\Bbb{H}_{-}$) and is defined near $(a, b)$. Then for $c \in (a, b)$ we have

$$ G_{-}(c) - G_{+}(c) = \Delta(c) = 2\pi i n(c). $$

---

Conversely, if $n$ is the restriction of an analytic function near $(a, b)$, then using this function we can extend $G$ across $(a, b)$. Indeed, assume that $n$ is analytic on an open connected set $U$ which contains $(a, b)$ and does not wind $a$ or $b$. Then $G$ can be extended on all of $U$ by perturbing the contour of the defining integral of $G$. In fact, we have an explicit description of this extension in terms of $G$ and $n$. Since $U$ does not wind $a$ or $b$, $U \setminus (a, b)$ consists of two components $U_{+}$ and $U_{-}$, which touches $(a, b)$ from above and from below, resp. Then

$$ G_{+}(z) := \begin{cases}
G(z), & z \in U_{+} \\
G(z + 0^+i), & z \in (a, b) \\
G(z) + 2\pi i n(z), & z \in U_{-}
\end{cases} $$

is the desired extension of $G$ on $U$.

This also tells us that if we move from one sheet to another by crossing $(a, b)$, we get extra term $\pm 2\pi i n$ depending on the crossing direction. Consequently, sheets of $G$ are of the form $G + 2\pi i k n$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.